# Prohibiting import in Python using import statement

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

I want to restrict the import of some modules in Python 3 (but for the scope of this question let's say that I want to restrict any import). This is the way I am trying to do it:

```
def __import__(self, *args, **kwrgs):
    raise ImportError("Imports are not allowed")

import math

print math.sqrt(4)
```

It is my understanding that this should raise exception, and it is based on that document - https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#importsystem that says

> The search operation of the import statement is defined as a call to the __import__() function, with the appropriate arguments.

However, it does not. I would greatly appreciate an explanation as to why and suggestions how to accomplish my goal

Comment: `import module` calls the builtin function `__import__('module')`, not `module.__import__()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had a misunderstanding: the docs are not suggesting to define your own `__import__` function within the module.   What they are trying to say is that when you have an import statement like

```
import mymodule
```

then the way in which the name `mymodule` is resolved here is by calling [the *built-in* function `__import__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#__import__) in this manner:

```
__import__('mymodule')
```

If you want to prevent a module from being imported successfully, you can just put any syntax error in there, e.g. putting this as first lines in the file:

```
# my_unimportable_file.py
error error error
```

Comment: Ah, thank you. Writing \__builtins__.__import__ = my_custom_function did what I wanted

Comment: Your last suggestion is not very helpful though: you can't do that to prevent people from importing built-in modules.

Comment: Show me a way to prevent importing built-in modules, and I will show you a way around it.

Comment: consider your challenge accepted. \__builtins__.__import__ = import_rewrite; \__import__ = import_rewrite;
This way you can't import using import command, \__import__ function nor can you import importlib
Tell me the way to bypass that, and that would be genuinely helpful

Comment: I will just take one of the loader classes from `().__class__.__base__.__subclasses__()` and use it.  There's always a bunch of them in there because they are created and used at interpreter startup.

Comment: So...what's the verdict? How do we "restrict any import" as OP asked?  @DmitryTorba, in Colab, when I try to run `__builtins__.__import__  = import_rewrite` (for my do-nothing `import_rewrite()` function, it hangs as if it's in an infinite loop.  Minimum example: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1XsugeC4GBLjsXKnElKdJ-BNd4hndzgp3?usp=sharing

Answer (score 4):

The statement `import module_name` calls the builtin function `__import__` with the parameter `'module_name'`. It doesn't, and in fact can't, call `module_name.__import__()` as you expected, because the module itself hasn't been loaded yet.

A nice way to achieve what you want is to check the `__name__` global variable in the non importable module. when it is run, it should be equal to `'__main__'`, but when it is imported, it would be some other string constructed from its name. Therefore you can try:

```
if __name__ != '__main__':
    raise ImportError("Imports are not allowed")
```

Comment: That won't work if I want to restrict the import of the builtin module

Comment: You're right. You should add this requirement to your question :)